# How to initialize Ember model id?

Tags: ember.js

I have an EmberJS model, which is initialized from a JSON object. This JSON object used to contain  an `id` variable, but now its name is changed. Is there a way to tell the model what to use as `id` from the JSON? There are functions which use the model's `id` variable, so the best way would be to set `id` to be a reference of one of the model's variable.

Comment: its not an option to change the JSON? how do you initialize it? you can do something like this in the serializer when we talk about the API.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a serializer (`ember generate serializer [name]`) where the name matches your model, and set the `primaryKey` that should be used instead of the default `id`.

> If your backend uses a key other than id you can use the serializer's primaryKey property to correctly transform the id property to id when serializing and deserializing data.

```
// app/serializers/modelName.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_ids

Alternatively, you can use the serializer to copy a value TO the `id` property via the `normalizeResponse` method if you prefer to maintain the primaryKey as `id`:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  normalizeResponse(store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
    payload.data.id = payload.data.newModelId;
    delete payload.data.newModelId;

    return this._super(...arguments);
  }
});
```

Comment: I upvoted, however, it does not work for me. Maybe because I am using ember 1.12?

Comment: oh, yes, I'm not positive exactly which one, but the above code is for v2.x+. I didn't start using Ember until after version 2.0, so I don't know how to do this in earlier versions.